# Switch selection of specific polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, point, select, point-in-polygon

I'm using ArcGIS 10 desktop version. I have a number of polygons, let's say 300, in a layer. Each polygon contains information of schools, ranging from 100 to 250 points, in a separate point layer. For example polygon "1A" will have all its points marked "1A" in the attribute table along with all other information. Same goes for polygon "2A" and "3A" and so on.

**Problem:**

As the points have been marked using GPS, a number of points of "1A" actually fall in other polygons, lets say "3A". Is there any idea through which I can select the points that belong to 1A but fall outside the polygon 1A. Switch selection does not work here as it selects the points of all other polygons.

Comment: If your point features all have the correct ID value ("1A" or "2A") then you can simply do a select by attribute on the point layer for whatever polygon layer you are wanting to select points for.

Comment: @polyGeo: I want to select the ones that fall outside the respective polygon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [spatial join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000) to extract the label of the polygon under each point. Then you have the attributes from points and underlying polygon in the same table, so you can "select by attribute" the mismatching points.

```
"field_pol" <> "field_point"
```

Comment: how do I select mismatching points...?

Comment: you will find the new field in the attribute table. use the field name as in the example above.

Comment: I did same (select via attributes) but it says invalid sql statment!

Comment: what about "field" = "fieldp" then switch selection ? Can you add a print screen of your "select by attribute" window ?

Comment: Thank you... It had changed data type... string vs double... sorted!

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that "1A" is in your attribute table of the points, you can do this:

- select all points labeled "1A"
- create a feature class with only polygon 1A
- use Select by location with your point layer and the feature class from above and setting "Remove from currently selected features"

[image]

By playing around with the different selection methods in the dropdown list you can probably work out a better workflow with your specific data, or you can automate this one in ModelBuilder or Python script.

Comment: It did not work as I'm working in two different files. Selection by layer dint give any results